# Retrieve last & second to last record from model with Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on a text editor. I want the user to work on the most recent draft while also letting the review the second to last draft.

I tried the following:

```
App.ReviewerRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var allDrafts = this.store.all('draft');
    var secondToLastDraft = allDrafts[allDrafts.length-2];
    return secondToLastDraft;
  }
});
```

Then I tried:

```
App.ReviewerRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var allDrafts = this.store.all('draft');
    var secondToLastDraft = this.store.find('draft',[allDrafts.length-2]);
    return secondToLastDraft;
  }
});
```

None of which returned a draft.

My main concern is that I only want to retrieve one draft in order to use an object controller. I'd appreciate any advice.

EDIT:
Here's the problem.
Each document has many drafts. The user should have access to the most recent two drafts of a given document.
I assume I do not need an EmberArrayController for drafts, since only the last two drafts are needed, which shall also be displayed in two different templates/components/views.
It's most confusing to me where I shall put the method to return, say, the last draft.
In Rails I'd make it a class method on the Draft model.
Thanks for the help so far.

Github repo: https://github.com/den1k/whiteink/tree/master/ember

Answer (score 2):

Use [`objectAt`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_objectAt):

```
App.ReviewerRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var allDrafts = this.store.all('draft');
    var count = allDrafts.get('length');
    return allDrafts.objectAt(count-2) || allDrafts.objectAt(count-1); 
  }
});
```

Comment: 1) You probably want `store.find()` instead of `store.all()`. 2) Since either method returns promise, you'll want something like `return this.store.find("draft").then(function (allDrafts) { /*...*/ })`

Comment: @panta82 the OP is probably calling store.find() in some parent route, so its best to avoid calling the same request twice. Hence store.all() is more suitable.

Comment: @panta82 2. The all() method does return a promise, but a DS.RecordArray which extends Ember.ArrayProxy, where the objectAt method is defined.

Comment: Got it. I played around in JSBin and the combination of find() and DS.RecordArray didn't work for me. Probably because I didn't have records loaded in a parent route. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I can't seem to access the draft from what is returned. See github repo.

Comment: @den1k you need to make sure that this.store.find("draft") is called at least once in some parent route. this.store.all("draft") returns all the drafts that are **available in the local cache**.